# How to define a Combitimetable through a script in Dymola?

Tags: scripting, simulation, modelica, dymola, timetable

I am trying to perform several simulations in a sequence using a for loop in a script. From simulation to simulation, the only variable to change is the file path of a Combitimetable.

I propagated the variable fileName in order to assign a new path in each iteration. However, when the model reads the extension, changes the timeScale and the resolution is lower than needed. I tried to propagate timeScale too, but without changes. Is there a function to define the Combitimetable variables? Is my only alternative to merge all tables and split the results manually?

Example of the script on a single run (without the for loop):

```
filePath="RL_30_200g";
dymolaPath = "modelica://customTILComponents/Combitables/Combitimetable_"+filePath+".txt";
fileName= ModelicaServices.ExternalReferences.loadResource(dymolaPath);
result ="Full_Year_Simulation_"+filePath;
timeScale = 1/3600;
```

```
translateModel ("customTILComponents.MA_Santoro.FullModels.OptiHorst_FullModel_New_Year_Simulation_Batch");
simulateModel(startTime=0,stopTime=8860,numberOfIntervals=300,method="Dassl",tolerance=0.000001,resultFile=result);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure where your problem is and how you change `fileName`. In your question `timeScale` is also not used anywhere. Anyway, here is how I would do it: add a parameter to your model for `fileName`. Since it is a string, the only way to change it is via a modifier which can be included in the model name of the `simulateModel` command.

Here is an example: In your model with the time table, propagate the parameter `fileName`:

```
model MyModel
  parameter String fileName="NoName" "File where matrix is stored";
  Modelica.Blocks.Tables.CombiTable1Ds combiTable1Ds(
    tableOnFile=true,
    tableName="x",
    fileName=fileName) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp ramp(duration=1) annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,-10},{-40,10}})));
equation 
  connect(ramp.y, combiTable1Ds.u) annotation (Line(points={{-39,0},{-12,0}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end MyModel;
```

Then change the value of `fileName` in every loop.
Here we assume that there are three .mat files available in the workspace, named `First.mat`, `Second.mat` and `Third.mat`.

```
function batchSim
  input String fileNames[:] = {"First", "Second", "Third"};
algorithm 
  for f in fileNames loop
    simulateModel("MyModel(fileName=\""+f+".mat\")", stopTime=1, resultFile="Full_Year_Simulation_"+f);
  end for;
  annotation(__Dymola_interactive=true);
end batchSim;
```

This works quite well, but the downside is that the model will be recompiled in every iteration of the for loop, as the modifier has changed. If this is a big problem, define all file paths in a string vector in the model and add an integer parameter for the index. Then use the command `simulateExtendedModel` and change only the index via the parameters `initialNames` and `initialValues`.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer by marco (so same model and same external files) an alternative is to make a script such as:

```
fileNames := {"First", "Second", "Third"};
Advanced.AllowStringParameters:=true;
translateModel("MyModel");
for f in fileNames loop
  fileName:=f;
  simulateModel("MyModel", stopTime=1, resultFile="Full_Year_Simulation_"+f);
end for;
```

Unfortunately it seems you cannot turn that into a function.